Retrieving funds from Vesting smart contract using Kuber throws missing Utxo error
I am stuck in the PPP 0403 Off-chain Code with Kuber.
While I can successfully make transaction using Kuber Playground and vesting smart contract to vest ADA from my wallet, I cannot retrieve them afterwards. I always get the following error ❌ KubærApi [Status 400] : Input Utxo missing in utxo map : 4b761ef95c14c0a2e8721b3e406e20ba0f2cceb2d2c1507e9615448aa67253e4#0. I have checked using both Cardanoscan and Blockfrost that the utxos I am refering to are available. Has anyone faced a similar problem or has any suggestions on troubleshooting?
